# How can I fix this error when working with winotify package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I imported the winotify package and was just testing making a new notification. I followed the exact same code outlined by: https://pypi.org/project/winotify/

However, when running, I am getting this error:

```
PS C:\Python27\piazza-project> & c:/Python27/python.exe c:/Python27/piazza-project/get_piazza_notifs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Python27/piazza-project/get_piazza_notifs.py", line 7, in <module>
    from winotify import Notification
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winotify\__init__.py", line 58
    def _run_ps(*, file='', command=''):
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure about what to do, I'm still new to python. I don't want to edit the third party file.

Comment: The code is for Python 3 not Python 2.7.

Comment: I can only use this package with python 3?

Comment: Seems to be the case. Only reasonable, as the package was first released in 2021, already after the EOL of python 2